# How to get data from serial port?

Tags: c#, windows-services, serial-port, listener

I have this code but I don't know how to get the data and put it in one variable :

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            /* This WaitHandle will allow us to shutdown the thread when
               the OnStop method is called. */
            _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            /* Create the thread.  Note that it will do its work in the
               appropriately named DoWork method below. */
            _thread = new Thread(DoWork);

            /* Start the thread. */
            _thread.Start();
        }
```

and then in the DoWork I have the following :

```
private void DoWork()
        {

//opening serial port 
            SerialPort objSerialPort;
            objSerialPort = new SerialPort();

            objSerialPort.PortName = "COM2";
            objSerialPort.BaudRate = 11500;
            objSerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            objSerialPort.DataBits = 16;
            objSerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            objSerialPort.Open();
```

So, I open the port but where to start getting the data ??? How to initialize the variable ? The received message will be of the form 52 45 41 44 45 52 30 31 where 41 44 45 53 30 is the message in hexadecimal while 52 45 is the header and 31 CRC.

Please let me  know how to do it.

Thank you ....

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: yeah but I need to manipulate the data in doWork I dont want to call another functon

Comment: As per comment in my answer, I would like to ask if you know anything about **threading**? If you don't, I would advise that you do, as if this is run on a single thread, you WILL have a VERY slow application! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with serial port is just like working with files or sockets:

```
while ((bytesRead = objSerialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    var checksum = buffer[bytesRead - 1];

    if (VerifyChecksum(checksum, buffer, bytesRead))  // Check the checksum
    {
        DoSomethinWithData(buffer, bytesRead);  // Do something with this bytes
    }
}
```

Comment: So I will add this inside the DoWork??

Comment: Where and how to define the var bytestoRead, buffer , checksum ???
Sorry for this, I am a beginner.....

Comment: **buffer** can be defined in the **doWork** method, **checksum**, in this example, can be defined before the **while** loop and **bytesRead** can be defined (also) before while loop. As for **how**, the documentation should tell you how! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
String message = "";

While (true)
{
  if(objSerialPort.Read(buffer,0,1)>0)
  {
  message+= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(buffer).ToString();
  //Or you could call another function here that will DoSomething with each byte coming in!
  }

}
```

Should do the trick!

Comment: "System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(buffer).ToString();" can be safely replaced to "objSerialPort.ReadExisting()"

Comment: I'm used to using netMF, sorry! (so can only guarantee the former). But if **ReadExisting** works, than it is also a valid alteration!

Comment: I would also advise to include the creating of a new thread too!

Comment: Let me check this one. Thanks though

Comment: @BesaNeziri how did you get on?

Comment: I am trying to put this one on my existing code. When I receive the data i have to write it in the sql server database and check if all works. 
I am dividing the received bytes and get only the message without the header or the CRC

Comment: Well sure let me know if you have any issues :D